# Make my app launch when secret code entered?

Tags: android

How would I make my app launch when a secret code, such as `*#*#12345#*#*` is entered into the dialer?

I couldn't find a solution in the Android docs.

Comment: Why don't you just implement a splashscreen, on which you have to enter a code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I did it:

I changed my main activity to have no intent-filters:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ParentTrap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_parent_trap"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        </activity>
```

I then made a broadcast receiver with the intent filter action: `android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE`

I then added data to it. The entire thing is below:

```
<receiver android:name=".ParentTrap$Launch" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />

                <data
                    android:host="(secret code)"
                    android:scheme="android_secret_code" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Once done, make a class (I made the Launch class in my main class, extending BroadCast Receiver), then in the onReceive class, fire an intent to launch the activity.

Then typing `*#*#(secret code)#*#*` into the dialer will launch the app.

Comment: This is not working for me on Samsung Galaxy Note GT-N7000 with Android 4.1.2. Do we need to do something else too to make it work?

Comment: Yes I did create a blank activity. Please see my question related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901339/android-provider-telephony-secret-code-reserved-for-system-apps and please help if you can.

Comment: @Manish the post does not exist anymore. Did you find the issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Create a broadcast receiver with this action:

- [ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)

In the extras you find [the dialed number](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER).

*Edit:* Here is [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) for broadcast receiver.

Comment: i dont think you are able to intercept the simple dial action without actually calling...

Comment: Ah, I was talking about the *#*# secret codes, but I figured out how to use them :)

Comment: In that case, can you update your post or answer your own question, for the benefit of others?

Answer (score 0):

Insted broadcast reciever maybe you should register to proper activity intent. For example [Intent.ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) looks promessing. Problem is how to filter intents to recive only this one specyfic number. I suspect that it would look like this (I'm gesing based on what I've found in documentation):

```
<action name=".YourAction">
    <intent-filter . . . >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <!-- data is crutial here, you have to figuire it out exacly yourself -->
        <data android:scheme="tel" android:path="yourSpecyficSecretCode" />
    </intent-filter>
</action>
```

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#scheme). Use LogCat to see what exacly intent contatins then you can filter this properly.