# Android development: hook shortcut on keyboard when phone app activity is focused

Tags: android, keyboard-shortcuts, android-softkeyboard

It's a specific question and I've done a bit of Android development before, but not so deep into the system management.

So I need to create an app which run in background (this part is OK) and to launch automatically an activity of the app when a special shortcut (let's say #123*6) is typed from the phone app software keyboard on the phone.

Can you please indicate me if it's possible, and if yes, what API/Component I should use? Can't find something relevant on the Web.

Comment: I know there's a lot of security around the input devices, but a lot of insecurity around the Accessibility functionality that e.g. password managers use. Check out [Building Accessibility Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html) for more info. Thanks to the question, I'm about to check it out too.

Comment: I see a View Text Changed event on the [`AccessibilityEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) page that can respond to changed in an `EditText` (not password box tho). While not exactly what you asked for, it could help. Depending on "why", you might find the general gesture listener useful too.

Comment: I found these subjects which fill my needs guys : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724192/make-my-app-launch-when-secret-code-entered  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769166/programmatically-enter-secret-code-like-4636-on-android .  However, I didn't managed to get my secret code to launch an activity.

Comment: Nope definitly not :( On a HTC One S and Samsung Galaxy S6 I didn't managed to get it working. I also checked these subjetcs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647314/secret-code-set-from-code-android & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188252/launch-hidden-app-when-secret-code-is-dialed. And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801355/launch-activity-in-android-via-dialpad-using-secret-code?noredirect=1#comment65025510_38801355. The BroadcastReceiver is never called even if I have the right authorizations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally got this working on the HTC device. The fact is Samsung phones doesn't seems to react to secret codes ...

I simply have **this manifest** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuBrowser"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".ShortcodeService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".ShortcodeReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
                <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="1992" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

My service is simply checking for the right permissions for Android M (6.0), because the security has changed a bit. We now have to declare permission on-the-fly during the application runtime, and not at installation.

**My activity**:

```
public class MenuBrowser extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("USSDBrowser", "Start app");

        //if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS}, 10);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ShortcodeService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_browser);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_menu_browser, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my **receiver** is like this :

```
public class ShortcodeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String defaultCode = "1992";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("USSDBrowser", "Intent received");

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE")) {
            String code = intent.getDataString();

            if(code.equals("android_secret_code://" + defaultCode)) {
                Log.d("USSDBrowser", "Code received !!! ");
            }
            //Intent in = new Intent(context, MenuBrowser.class);
            //context.startActivity(in);

            Toast.makeText(context, "You typed a shortcode, hype !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But now I tested that and it's working for HTC One S (Android 4.1.1) and Aquaris E4 (Android 4.4.2).

The phones tested that does not capture secret code intents are : Samsung Galaxy S4 and Galaxy S6 (Android 6.0).