# Launch Activity in android via Dialpad using Secret Code

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I just want to launch activity via **Secret Code** .

Although , there are many solutions available for this problem but none of them worked for me. It seems like **BroadcastReceiver** is not listening .

I am using Mi4i MIUI 7.

Here's my code. Please Help!!

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.jatin.myapplication2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

I have even tried the  below commented code , but that didn't work.

**MySecretCodeReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.jatin.myapplication2;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

 /**
 * Created by Jatin on 05-Aug-16.
 */
 public class MySecretCodeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE")) {
        String uri  =  intent.getDataString();
        String sep[] = uri.split("://");
        if (sep[1].equalsIgnoreCase("1234"))
        {
            Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.jatin.myapplication2.MainActivity");
            context.startActivity(launchIntent);

        }
        else if (sep[1].equalsIgnoreCase("5678")) {
            Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("net.one97.paytm");
            context.startActivity(launchIntent);
        }

//            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
//            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//            setResultData(null);
//            context.startActivity(i);

       }
    }

}
```

I have also tried putting android:host="1234" in manifest ,still not getting desired results

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"></uses-permission>
<receiver android:name="receivers.MySecretCodeReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE"  />
        <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I can't manage to make it works on HTC (Android 4.1.1) or Samsung (Android 6.0). I use the PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, and also the READ_PHONE_STATE permissions. I have my receiver in application like you in manifest. I also tried to programmatically register the receiver from a service, called from my main activity. I read the 6 or 7 subjects about this and couldn't log something in the BroadcastReceiver ...

Comment: Same here. I am unable to make it run on any samsung device.

Comment: @Alex whats ur app's Target API level?

Comment: minimum API 16 to 23, and you ?

Comment: @Alex After releasing  marshmallow android has made some changes.Now you have to use permissions at run time rather than static declarations in manifest.Here's the link '[Runtime Permissions in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)`

Comment: yeah I saw that thanks :) I managed to make it work on non-Samsung devices. And I made a sample app which require permissions on Android M at the runtime, it works like a charm. I think it's Samsung stock ROM which shutdown the SECRET_CODE intent...

Comment: @Alex How did u manage in case of samsung devices and marshmallow ? Are you working with camera2 ?  I.m still searching could you please help me , ?

Comment: @Alex I mean , all non-samsung devices , my apologies for typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it** ....

We have to register our **MySecretCodeReceiver** as a <**receiver**> within the <**application**> element in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

And , Its Done. :)