# Capture input from physical laser scanner outside a Xamarin Entry

Tags: c#, xamarin, input, barcode-scanner

I'm making a warehouse stock Android app with Xamarin.Forms (XAML + C#) for PDAs with builtin laser barcode scanners.

Workers scan barcodes into an Entry, called `ProductBarcode`, along with a newline character, in order to trigger the *Completed* event in that Entry, so it can be captured and handled through an event handler, with a code like this.

```
private void ProductBarcode_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Product.IsValidBarcode(ProductBarcode.Text))
        DisplayAlert("Error", "Invalid Product Barcode.", "Okay");
    else /* Use of ProductBarcode (irrelevant) */;
}
```

It works fine. But the problem is that workers often touch the screen (background of the view), and the Entry loses focus. So when they try to scan the next code, they often press the physical scan button (like in EDA50K or similar devices) and the input is not read into the Entry, and it gets lost.

I was wondering if it is possible (or not) to capture the input sent to the background of the `ContentPage` and send it to the correct Entry. Or even if it is possible to capture the input from wherever in the screen.

Comment: If it is just a built-in scanner and information on the mechanism and API is not shown, there will be no advice or answer. Please add information such as device vendor, model number, documentation, and SDK/API.

Comment: Reference device is Honeywell EDA50K, and it works out of the box, so I guess it just send the text read as if it were written with the virtual keyboard. I also think it won't be easy, or even possible. Documentation is [here](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-ae/-/media/en/files-public/technical-publications/computers/eda50k/eda50k_ug__en_07302018.pdf).

Comment: There is a technique called global keyboard hooks that you may not be able to do with Android (or you could do it in the past but not now). [Android development: hook shortcut on keyboard when phone app activity is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38618323/9014308) It would be nice to be able to use it somehow, but other non-built-in scanners can often switch between keyboard input emulation mode and serial port mode. If the device supports such a switch, consider switching to serial port mode. https://www.honeywellaidc.com/resources/support

Answer (score 1):

I came across this looking for Forms support for android and ios for scanning barcodes.  My previous application was a native xamarin android app and I used this to universally capture scanned input:

```
        public override void HandleDispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Characters)) {
            HandleInput(e.Characters);
        }
        else if (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Up) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter) {
                HandleInput(_barcodeChacacters);
                _barcodeChacacters = "";
            }
            else {
                _barcodeChacacters += e.DisplayLabel;
            }
        }
    }
```

That was inside code for a hidden Fragment I had added to my base view.  I know the event in xamarin forms droid is named slightly differently, but I'm assuming it works the same.  I haven't tried it because I need a solution that works for Android and iOS.  But since you're just targeting android, hope that helps, if you still need a solution after all this time.